# Is this an example of LINQ-to-SQL?

Tags: c#, linq-to-sql, sql-server-ce

I made a little WPF application with a SQL CE database.

I built the following code with LINQ to get data out of the database, which was surprisingly easy. So I thought "this must be LINQ-to-SQL".

Then I did "add item" and added a "LINQ-to-SQL classes" .dbml file, dragged my table onto the Object Relational Designer but it said, "The selected object uses an unsupported data provider."

So then I questioned whether or not the following code actually is LINQ-to-SQL, since it indeed allows me to access data from my SQL CE database file, yet officially "LINQ-to-SQL" seems to be unsupported for SQL CE.

So is the following "LINQ-to-SQL" or not?

```
using System.Linq;
using System.Data.Linq;
using System.Data.Linq.Mapping;
using System.Windows;

namespace TestLinq22
{
    public partial class Window1 : Window
    {
        public Window1()
        {
            InitializeComponent();

            MainDB db = new MainDB(@"Data Source=App_Data\Main.sdf");
            var customers = from c in db.Customers
                            select new {c.FirstName, c.LastName};
            TheListBox.ItemsSource = customers;
        }
    }

    [Database(Name = "MainDB")]
    public class MainDB : DataContext
    {
        public MainDB(string connection) : base(connection) { }
        public Table<Customers> Customers;
    }

    [Table(Name = "Customers")]
    public class Customers
    {
        [Column(DbType = "varchar(100)")]
        public string FirstName;

        [Column(DbType = "varchar(100)")]
        public string LastName;
    }

}
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

[This msdn article](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb546181.aspx) notes that while sdf is supported by the LINQ to SQL runtime, it is not supported by the designer.

To Quote:

- The LINQ to SQL runtime and the SQLMetal command-line tool support SQL Server Compact 3.5.
- The Object Relational Designer does not support SQL Server Compact 3.5.

Answer (score 5):

Yes, that's LINQ to SQL. It's using `System.Data.Linq.DataContext`, which is LINQ to SQL. It sounds like the *designer* doesn't support your provider, but LINQ to SQL itself does.

(Or the designer is being picky about your connection string, and would cope if you changed it a little bit. That sounds as likely as anything...)